# BillingClient always returns SERVICE_DISCONNECTED

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library

So I have a billing client which I instantiate with

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build();
```

I then call

```
billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(int responseCode) {
            //TODO: use this for stuff
            com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase.PurchasesResult result;
result = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    Timber.d(result.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            //TODO: use this for stuff
            Timber.d("something went wrong ");
        }
    });
```

for whatever reason the breakpoint on the timber line always returns disconnected. can anyone provide insight or an example to how i would do this?

Comment: i faced the same problem.how did you solve this?

Comment: I'm running into this right now and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: See if you BillingClient is actually ready, Please refer to my answer on the below thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332090/testing-billing-with-static-products-returns-service-disconnected/63332353#63332353

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was not using a version of my apk that was signed with the right version numbering and such. Once I fixed that I was able to connect to play services and figure out what i wanted.

Comment: How'd you fix that?

Comment: It was just ensuring that the versioning on the apk and play services was the same. I have various logging and what not for that in app, so just making sure that matched what the play console says

Comment: @1tSurge you mean about the app versionNumber and versionCode? or maybe the billing dependency version added in the `build.gradle`? Otherwise, where do you check?

Comment: I am also curious about this, I ran into the same issue and I have not been able to fix it. What do you mean by the apk and play services versioning being the same?

Answer (score 9):

I came across this problem.
Be also sure to start the connection:

```
mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mContext).setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener).build();

        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished: BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK ");

                }


            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }


        });
```

Comment: At first I thought your comment wasn't helpful, however I have been able to check for myself that if you receive a SERVICE_DISCONNECTED response, then you need to call (again) to the startConnection() method. Thumbs up!

Comment: @xarlymg89 is enough to call the startConnection() in the onBillingServiceDisconnected() or do we have to call it also in the onBillingSetupFinished() when the billingResponseCode == 
SERVICE_DISCONNECTED?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer this, but i was missing this permission in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

hope that helps someone

Comment: That's not required since the version 1.0 https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#release-1_0

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom rom or rooted device it probably won't work.

> Run a system image on which the Google Play client application is **preinstalled**.
> If Google Play is **not preinstalled** in the system image, your application won't be able to communicate with the Google Play licensing server.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up