# Testing billing with static products returns SERVICE_DISCONNECTED

Tags: android, android-billing

I am upgrading the in-app billing in my app from [Version 3](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) to [newer code](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview).  Version 3 is working fine and it production in my app right now but I've read it will be deprecated eventually.

When I try to test the purchase flow using a [static product id](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#billing-testing-static) (android.test.purchased), the `BillingResult` result code only returns -1 with a debug message of "Service connection is disconnected".  AFAIK, there is no service connection in the newer library but there was in Version 3.

If I use a real in-app product code it tells me I've already purchased it, which is correct but I need to test the actual purchase flow.

I am testing this on an actual device (Pixel 3 XL), not the emulator. I've tried testing it on a separate device that is logged in with a test account (not developer) but I get the same results.

UPDATE: I setup a real (test) in-app managed product in the Developer Console, then installed my app on a device that is logged in with a test (non-developer) account and I'm still getting the "Service connection is disconnected" error.  I feel it's something outside of the code but not sure what.

UPDATE 2: I created a new project with nothing in it except the billing code and it worked so there's something in my app that is causing it to break.

UPDATE 3: I created a new project and imported the code from the broken app into it and still getting the same error message.  I feel, now, there's something with my package name and Google's servers that's returning the error message.

UPDATE 4: I created a blank project but gave it the same package name as my broken app and the billing worked, so it's not the package name.  Now my guess is there's something from the old AIDL billing code (Version 3) that is interfering.

SOLUTION!!! in the `application` node in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I had this: `tools:node="replace"`.  Removed that attribute and billing now works.

```
    mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == OK) {
                    final Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                    if (purchasesResult.getResponseCode() == OK) {

                        final List<Purchase> purchases = purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();

                        for (final Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            CommonUtils.showToast(mActivity, "disconnected");
        }
    });
    
    
    mUnlockPremiumButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                final List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
                skuList.add(getString(R.string.inapp_premium_product_id));

                final SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkusList(skuList)
                    .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

                mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                        new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

                                for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                                    if (getString(R.string.inapp_premium_product_id).equals(skuDetails.getSku())) {

                                        final BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                                                .build();

                                        final BillingResult result = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity, flowParams);

                                        if (result.getResponseCode() == ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED)
                                        {
                                            CommonUtils.showToast(mActivity, getString(R.string.alert_purchased));
                                        }
                                        else if (result.getResponseCode() != OK)
                                        {
                                            //always returns a getResponseCode of -1 (service disconnected)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly indicates, the Billing Client is disconnected due to the following possible reasons.

1. You started the connection but the connection has not finished the setup yet.
   Possible race condition since startConnection is an asynchronous process. You can use
   billingClient.isReady() to check if it is available.
2. Your app may have lost the connection/internet after starting it.
3. Your device/emulator does not support Google Play Services.

The following is a working code in Billing API 3.0 with Android Version Targeted SDK 28.
As documented in Billing API Error Handling section (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate)  if the connection is lost, app must be responsible to reestablish the connection. I would recommend to use a Singleton class that holds the Billing API and use billingClient.isReady() method to check if the connection is successful, if not attempt to reestablish it. Provided you add logging in the BillingClientStateListener class override methods. I am skipping that code because it is straight forward and well documented in the link I provided above.

```
public class ApplicationBillingClient
{
static ApplicationBillingClient applicationBillingClient= null;
private static BillingClient billingClient;

private ApplicationBillingClient() {}

private static boolean isInitialized()
{
    return applicationBillingClient != null && billingClient != null;
}

private static void initialize(Context applicationContext)
{
    try
    {
        if(applicationContext != null)
        {
            applicationBillingClient = new ApplicationBillingClient();
            BillingClient.Builder builder=  BillingClient.newBuilder(applicationContext);
            builder.setListener(new PurchaseActivityListener());
            builder.enablePendingPurchases();
            billingClient = builder.build();
        }

        LogUtil.info("Initializing the Billing Client");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogUtil.error("Error while initializing billing client", ex);
    }

}

public static ApplicationBillingClient getInstance(Context applicationContext)
{
    if(isInitialized() == false)
    {
        initialize(applicationContext);
    }

    return  applicationBillingClient;
}

public void startConnection()
{
   billingClient.startConnection(new StateListener());
}

public boolean isReady()
{
    return billingClient.isReady();
}

public void getMonthlySubscription()
{
    try
    {
        if(billingClient.isReady())
        {
            SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
            skuBuilder.setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
            skuBuilder.setSkusList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{MONTHLY_BILLING_SUBSCRIPTION_SKU}));
            SkuDetailsParams params = skuBuilder.build();
            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsListener());
        }

    }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogUtil.error("Error while querying async SKU for Monthly Subscription", ex);
    }
  }
 }

 //In your activity
 ApplicationBillingClient appBillingClient = 
 ApplicationBillingClient.getInstance(applicationContext);
        if (appBillingClient.isReady() == false)
        {
            appBillingClient.startConnection();
        }
        else
        {
           appBillingClient.getMonthlySubscription();
        }
```

Comment: It's obvious you are trying really hard to appear smart by trying to figure this out.  Your efforts would be better spent building apps and let Google handle the really smart stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This was the application node, in the AndroidManifest, when the billing was breaking:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:node="replace">
    ...
</application>
```

removing `tools:node="replace"` fixed the billing.  Hopefully this will save someone the days I wasted.

Comment: I have tried this extensively and tools:replace is completely unrelated in your case it might worked because perhaps the time it takes in establishing the connection with multiple manifest flag might have caused delays in firing the activities. See below the actual answer. Please validate and confirm. Remove your answer to help the community with accurate information.

Comment: What are you talking about?  It did not work when I had the `tools:replace` attribute and it worked when I removed it.  The Billing Library has it's own AndroidManifest which is merged into mine when compiled.  According to the documentation the `tools:replace` attribute will "Replace the specified attributes in the lower-priority manifest with those from this manifest."  Maybe it's been fixed in the latest Billing Library.

Comment: KrisB - As a development community we should try to provide evidence or supporting documentation, magical answers do not help developers. If you read the documentation on manifest merge, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge, it is completely unrelated. The only explanation can be that your activity that starts the Billing Connection might have not properly merged into the main manifest. But that is something not the root cause. You can keep your answer to see if anybody else supports this case.

Comment: I submitted a bug to Google over a year ago, so they are currently looking into it.  I'm not at a Google engineer level to understand the inner workings of the Billing Library (and should not be expected to).  All I know is removing the `tools:replace` attribute from the AndroidManifest fixed the issue. I shouldn't be expect to know why. That is on Google.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133868032